# Media Query Works with Inline CSS, but not in a CSS File

Tags: css, media-queries

I am having an issue that I can't find an answer. I am using the `@media` code below and it works when I use inline CSS, but when I remove the inline code and add it to a CSS file it stops working.

Here is what I am using to test it.

```
@media all screen and (max-width: 480px) {body{font-size: 8px; }}

@media all screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {body{font-size: 28px; }}

@media all screen and (min-width: 769px) {body{font-size: 38px; }}
```

Any ideas why it stops working when it is added to an external CSS file??

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not enough information here to help.

Comment: please post your code to understand

Comment: Format your question please

Comment: @Scott Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to add the following in the `<head></head>` section of your `html` file.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

replacing `mystyle.css` with the name of your external css file.
...and in your css file something like:

```
body {
  @media all screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    font-size: 8px; 
  }
}
```